# Can a ContentProvider know anything about the app that is querying it?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm using a content provider to share data between two of my apps. It's not really sensitive data, but I'd prefer to keep out other snoopy apps if it's easy to do.

I don't want to have to create a unique permission type for my apps, which may raise questions from users who don't understand what it's for.

Is it possible for my content provider, in it's query method, to find out anything about the app that's calling query on it? If I could filter the package name and just return null for anything besides my own apps, it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yajin Zhou and Xuxian Jiang [here](http://yajin.org/papers/ndss13_contentscope.pdf) say:

> An app can protect its interface by either setting a property named
>   exported to false in its manifest ﬁle to ensure that the interface is
>   only available to itself or others with the `same user ID` or `deﬁning
>   custom permissions` to expose them only to apps that are granted these
>   custom permissions.

You can see more details in about `Securing Content Providers` in [**`An In-Depth Introduction to 
the Android Permission Model`**](https://www.owasp.org/images/c/ca/ASDC12-An_InDepth_Introduction_to_the_Android_Permissions_Modeland_How_to_Secure_MultiComponent_Applications.pdf).

Comment: I know about permissions. I was asking if I can find out anything about the caller so I can avoid using permissions.